# Seeking Advice on Transitioning Between Similar STEM Roles in Different U.S. Federal Agencies

Tags: job-change, government

I'm currently working for one federal government agency and would like to switch to another agency. Both roles are similar STEM-type jobs (but not the same), and both would have roughly the same pay. The switch has nothing to do with a lack of job satisfaction; one agency just has much more portability than the other. Has anyone had any success making a job switch of this kind?

Comment: The answer to the question you have asked is "Of course it has been done successfully at some point by someone. Probably by many. Apply and see what happens."

Comment: Yes; I have had success. However, our situation likely is completely different, as I don’t know your actual situation….

Comment: "Federal government agency" in what country?

Comment: Why did someone add in “U.S federal agencies” to the title that was never confirmed to be the case

Comment: @Donald That was an assumption on my part and an attempt to rescue an otherwise poorly worded title and question.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have experience in changing companies. Many people have experience in moving inside a large company. Changing government jobs is a combination of both.

Already being a federal government employee does make the switch easier, but you may find that the two government agencies have HR systems that don't mesh as well as they should.

When applying for a transfer within a company it isn't unusual for the hiring manager to be able to see your employment history with the company. They can see your pay, award history, and your annual reviews. If the two agencies HR systems don't talk to each other you may have to provide this data to the hiring manger.

> both would have roughly the same pay.

Make sure that you fully understand this. The pay can vary by agency, job title, and location. This is true even if the job description makes them seem equivalent.

As a contractor I have seen people change agencies. They mention the same hiccups, and adjustments that everybody else mentions when changing jobs.

Comment: Within the federal government, if you are performing the same type of work, you typically fall under the same series within the government itself.  This means that a Computer Scientist, at the United States Forest Service, will make the same money at another agency under the United States Department of Agriculture provided we are talking about the same General Schedule grade. Contractors for the government have different rules typically. Of course the author doesn't say if they are a federal employee or a contractor working under a contract for the federal government (or even which government)

Comment: Some US government agencies use the GS schedule, other agencies use pay bands. If you have to switch there might be a negotiation required.

Comment: I am familiar, in reality there won't be a negotiation, since unless you are going from an equivalent pay scale to a higher pay scale, you will be put in the equivalent pay scale at the same pay. There is very little negotiation that is possible with either with something like ACQDEMO or GS.

Answer (score 1):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### Yes, this happens all the time.

I have a bit of experience working for federal government agencies in Australia, and from what I've seen, it's relatively common for public servants to go from one federal agency to another one - or from a federal agency to a state or local agency, or vice versa.

This could be because of seeking a promotion to a higher level, being interested in working in another area of their field (e.g. someone in HR wanting to work in another area of HR), or simply because they have a non-ongoing employment contract that is ending and the other agency has a position open for hiring.

Moreover, policies like being able to transfer over accumulated leave from one agency to another as long as there's no breaks in between them make doing so even easier. You just finish work at one agency on a Friday, and go to work at another one on the Monday.

Answer (score 1):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

It is very common for public servant to switch agency in their career (called *mobilité* (mobility)), there is even an official website referencing those job offerings

At certain, very high, administrative rank you are actually required to switch every 2 yeats

I don't see any issue with a switch between agencies